# Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted

Tags: sql-server-2005, linked-server, service-broker

I have a service broker which calls a stores procedure sp_dequeue
queue -->
    ACTIVATION
    ( STATUS = ON,
    MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
    PROCEDURE_NAME = sp_dequeue,
    EXECUTE AS 'Username'
    );
In my sp_dequeue i am inserting record in to Linked server...
So when i am calling sp_dequeue from the magmnt studio it works fine. But when its called automatically via service broker i get this error msg :
"Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.".

In my linked server property i have checked "Be made using this security constraint" and provided oracle userid and pwd also i have added 'Username' mapping to oracle server.(Both username and pwd of oracle/SQL are different)
I googled for this error tried mostly all combination.
Pls do help me in sloving this problem.
using Sql server 2005 and oracle 10g

Comment: Could you share your answer?  Others might find it illuminating...

Comment: since i was using Sql 2005 forgot to enable TRUSTWORTHY bit ALTER DATABASE [DB_NAME] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explanation is given at [Why does feature … not work under activation?](http://rusanu.com/2006/01/12/why-does-feature-not-work-under-activation/). One solution is to enable TRUSTWORTHY, as you did. Another one is to use code signing, see [Signing an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/). Code signing is more complicated to deploy, but is required in very strict security environments because the TRUSTWORTHY flags opens the path to privilege escalation from `dbo` to `sysadmin`.

Comment: Thanks Remus Rusanu I will look in to it During Maintainence